# Is it possible to use Garch library with PHP? If yes then is there any code example in PHP?

Tags: prediction

I want to use Garch prediction. I studied different articles but unable to find any php code to use Fgarch class methods with php code. Please suggest some thing about this.

Thanks

Comment: Well, you studied the articles. If you understood the articles, you should be able to roll your own library. If you didn't understand the articles you could ask people about particular things that are unclear, so people can then help you understand how to roll your own.

Comment: I saw the tutorials which are using R language. code is on R language. I got the conclusion that i need to have web server supporting CGI or PHP and Rserve. If I leave all this to web administrator to do all this for me then i m stuck that how to use fgarch in my php code. I am not getting any solution. I think it may be possible or not possible.